# creation of a hidden navbar which is only visible at a defined size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently in training and to carry out a common thread project, I would like to stand out from my comrades who use a responsive navbar which displays a burger menu with a "hidden" menu which is displayed as a footer after reducing the window. (which only appears from a specific dimension)
For example the website https://www.parcasterix.fr/

I've been racking my brains for 3 days and I haven't found
Thank you

Comment: If the "_responsive navbar_" means the use of media queries, you can't beat your comrades.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own, tell what you've tried to achieve the goal and add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question if possible, at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the basics, make a container and use a nice natural HTML markup.

Naturally, elements are in `display:block`, this makes them following the page size. You can make them `display:inline-block`, so they stay on the same line, but will always follow the flow, and show their content.

No need to go complicated, at least on the beginning. But even after.

```css
.container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 140px;
}

div {
  border:  1px black solid;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px; /* Just to make it nicer */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <!-- Insert your content here and try to resize with the handle on the 
  bottom right corner -->
  
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>And some more. Hey did you notice?</div>
  <div>Elements are just following the flow!</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version, but assuming I've understood you correctly, you can do this simply with a CSS `@media` query. Hide the footer normally, show it when the screen size is small enough:

```
/* footer is hidden by default */
footer {
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width:400px) {
    footer {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Once the screen width is over 400px, the `footer` will be hidden